# problema con alineacion de tr

Tags: html

tengo un problema con el siguiente codigo html

```
<table style="width: 100%; padding-top: 7px; margin-top: 6px; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="addressheader" style=""><b>BILL TO</b></td>
    <td class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF; margin-right: 4px;"><b>DATE</b></td>
    <td class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>TERMS</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" class="address" >${record.billaddress}</td>
    <td colspan="" align="center">${record.trandate}</td>
    <td align="center">${record.terms}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>REF NUMBER</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">${record.otherrefnum}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Y el output que da es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para que record.trandate y record.terms se alineen con su respectivo titulo?

Gracias!

Comment: Los estilos que tenés son los que se ven ahí y nada mas? mostrá la hoja de estiilos CSS, el problema está ahí?

Comment: la hoja de estilos para las clases que estan ahi son:

        td.addressheader {
            font-size: 8pt;
            padding-top: 2px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
           color: #1c4c64;
        }
        td.address {
            padding-top: 0;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te confundiste en la colocación de `Colspan` y `Rowspan`. Quizá esto es lo que necesitas:

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 7px; margin-top: 6px; border-collapse: collapse;" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="addressheader" style=""><b>BILL TO</b></td>
            <td class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF; margin-right: 4px;"><b>DATE</b></td>
            <td class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>TERMS</b></td>
            <td class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>REF NUMBER</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="4" class="address" >${record.billaddress}</td>
            <td colspan="" align="center">${record.trandate}</td>
            <td align="center">${record.terms}</td>
            <td align="center">${record.otherrefnum}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Como podrás ver, los estilos no afectan solo tienes ahora dos `<tr>`. Le agregué una propiedad `border="1"` a `<table>` para que veas que en efecto ya están alineadas.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la estructura que tenias, tenias mal agregado un **colspan**, y celdas en blanco.

```html
<table style="width: 100%; padding-top: 7px; margin-top: 6px; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="addressheader" style=""><b>BILL TO</b></td>
      <td class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF; margin-right: 4px;"><b>DATE</b></td>
      <td class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>TERMS</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" rowspan="3" class="address">${record.billaddress}</td>
      <td colspan="" align="center">${record.trandate}</td>
      <td align="center">${record.terms}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="addressheader" align="center" style="width: 90px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #1c4c64; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>REF NUMBER</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">${record.otherrefnum}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```